# Ranking places based on distance and popularity

Tags: database, algorithm, sorting, geolocation, ranking

What should be the ideal way of ranking the records holding places, given that we have distance to a point + popularity of the place?

Assume I have the table designed with the following columns:

```
| PlaceID | Lat/Long | Distance | Popularity |
```

There are 2 factors to consider here for ranking(sorting) the records:
1. Distance: Sort records by distance in increasing order.
2. Popularity: Sort records by popularity in decreasing order.

How would the ideal way of ranking the places records considering both of these factors to give users a best places-search experience?

Answer (score 1):

You could use many ways. One of the simplest is using a value for the importance of popularity and a value for the importance of distance.

Given a place *p* you could calculate the importance of the place *I(p)* by using the popularity *P(p)* and the distance *D(p)*. You should decide or find the best values for the weights *a* and *b*.

I(p) = a * P(p) - b * D(p)